# Send SMS from android on special number (Not phone number)

Tags: android, sendmessage, smsmanager

*App is for my personal use, so no issue with Play store policies.*

For regular phone number the `SmsManager` works perfectly.

I have something different.

I am receiving message from some special number ex. **JOHN.1234567@domain.com**, see snap from sms details. Note: In above number the Numeric value is not phone number.

[image]

First I will show you how I am working

I have created below observer and I am getting message properly.

```
String url = "content://sms/";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
this.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver()
    .registerContentObserver(uri, true, new MessageObserver(new Handler(), this));
```

Now in this I used content observer to fetch the message details like below.

```
Uri loUriAllMessages = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
            Cursor loCursor = moContext.getContentResolver().query(
                    loUriAllMessages, null, null, null, "_id DESC");
if (loCursor != null && loCursor.getCount() > 0) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Cursor Count: " + loCursor.getCount());
    if (loCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        final int liMessageId = loCursor.getInt(loCursor
                                .getColumnIndex("_id"));

        final String lsMessageText = loCursor.getString(loCursor
                                .getColumnIndex("body"));

        String lsPhoneNumber = loCursor.getString(loCursor
                                .getColumnIndex("address"));
        final String lsDate = loCursor.getString(loCursor
                                .getColumnIndex("date"));
        String lsType = loCursor.getString(loCursor.getColumnIndex("type"))
                                .trim();
        long llTime = Long.parseLong(lsDate);
    }
}
```

All above things work perfectly.

In `lsPhoneNumber` field I am getting `JOHN.1234567@domain.com`

Now from my app if I send message using `SmsManager` on this number then it did not working, all message fail.

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
ArrayList<String> loParts = smsManager.divideMessage(message);
smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(number, null, loParts, null, null);
```

But if I go to Messaging app and use same above in send To field and send message then successfully sent on that number.

In short manually sending on the same working fine, But using `SmsManager` getting fail.

Hopping for the proper guidelines.